# How to avoid reading file system more than once

Tags: c#, performance, loops, filesystems

I got a few classes, which look into directories and subdirectories to check if the structure of these folders and files fit to the class-requirements. E.G. I got a JPEG-Class which looks in all subdirectories for any .jpeg. Some classes are even more complex where some directories and subdirectories need to have specific names and should contain some files with specified extensions.

Therefore I currently have the problem that I need to read the file system more than once to do these calculations as the classes have different requirements which can't be solved in one loop.

What I'm doing so far: I've implemented a loop over the file system with `Directory.GetFiles(path)`and `Directory.GetDirectories(path)` for every class and check if the structure is readable by my class

My question is: How can I improve my performance. I think it would be a big performance increase if I can store the file-system (directories and subdirectories from the selected path) into my memory, maybe in a tree-structure to avoid multiple file-system-calls? Is this the best behaviour? Or do you think this wouldn't bring a performance boost? Are there other ways I could do to get some improvements regarding the performance?

If the tree is the best solution - how would you implement it?

```
public class TreeNode
{
   List<TreeNode> nodes;
   FileInfo currentFileInfo;
   DirectoryInfo currentDirectoryInfo;
}
```

Is this structure suitable for my issue?

Regards

Comment: How about opposite organization - browse through each file and directory and for each file process/check in loop by each of you processing class.

Comment: I tried this but as I mentioned it is quite difficult because every processing class needs different information. Some of them only need a single file, others need whole directories, subdirectories or other properties. I would need to store the information somehow I guess to proceed them afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have successfully improved performance earlier by reading all the file information first and analyze it later by different classes. According to your question, yes, I'd recommend doing so.

I cannot know how your "filetype specific" classes work. But in general, if you create a tree as data structure, you'll have some work to maintain the nodes and to traverse.

Why not simply creating a `List`, an `ArrayList`or a `Collection` and `Hashtable`elements like this:

```
ArrayList directoryInformation = new ArrayList();
...
...
Hashtable fileEntry = new Hashtable();
fileEntry.add("name", theFileName);
fileEntry.add("type", theFileType);
fileEntry.add("path", theFilePath);
...
...
directoryInformation.add (fileEntry);
```

Once the list is built, your classes can simply loop through the list and get the information needed from the `Hashtable` entries. Further by adding the path to each element, you flatten the tree structure so you'll have to act recursively only once.

The only disadvantage of the `Hashtable`s is that it is not typed, so the compiler won't cough if you add some wrong strings. But it returns value by being flexible and fast to write.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! I thought about using a simple List but then I would suffer problems in some classes where I need to receive information about directory and subdirectory or files laying in directories such as "File with name XY: What is the name of the directory?" - In this case I would have to loop through the loop again, wouldn't I ? Maybe if I use FileInformation instead of a HashTable? Or save parent-path as a value in my hashtable... hm anyway +1 for your answer!

Comment: Glad to help :-) - Yes, the solution you'll chose depends on how much work it is to alter the existing helper classes. If you look at the code of those classes, is it a big work to change from accessing the file system to interpreting lists and strings? - Finally, if I understand right, you'd "loop several times" anyway. I'd find it much more elegant to loop several times to a prepared uniform list, or even simply _query_ that list, than to loop several times through a file system. If you create the list a clever way, your service class can just query it, so you won't "feel" the loops.